# MIPI CSI2 DPHY interface on the long length cable

Tags: signal-integrity, csi, mipi

Now I'm working with MIPI CSI2 DPHY. The situation is the camera and the processor(SoC) are connected using long flex cable(with more than 2 connectors). Due to the MIPI-CSI spec (I ref. from NVIDIA Jetson Xavier NX Product Design Guide), it says that the trace length should not be more 300mm.(1.5Gbps) or 150mm.(2.5Gbps).
Are there any solutions available to allow MIPI DPHY can be used at 1.5-2.5Gbps on long cable?
Now I've found that using Re-timer or Re-driver ICs is the interesting one. But are there any more solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Most situations where MIPI must be carried over longer distances will use a coax link bridge, such as FPD-Link III or GMSL. This sidesteps the CSI-2 distance limitations allowing up to 10m in some cases.

Here's a GMSL serializer board: https://www.framos.com/en/products/ffa-gmsl-ser-v1a-26298

And complementary de-serializer: https://www.framos.com/en/products/ffa-gmsl-des-v2a-27240

MIPI has introduced APHY as their long-reach solution, which also supports bidirectional Ethernet on the same link. Read more about APHY here: https://www.mipi.org/specifications/a-phy

MIPI C/DPHY also has options to increase cable length and/or bandwidth by modifying the PHY signal. On the transmit side you can enable TxEQ (pre-emphasis); on the receiver you can enable RxEQ (receive equalization) if the Nano supports it. You could also see if you can obtain a cable EQ filter that will boost the signal at the receiver.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer.